# Make a mask from a black and white video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I have created a black and white video of a transition that I want to use in the video editor but I see that the masking tools require a vector type object. Is it possible to simply use the black and white channels in the video I created to mask a video in the sequencer or to quickly create a vector mask from a black and white video to then be used in the video editor? Basically I want the top video layer to show in the white areas of the video and the bottom layer to show in the black area.

Answer (score -3):

I will answer my own question by posting this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXsrkg31VRI